# How to solve failure name image on seed using faker Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I create a table , this table named book

I create a seeder to add data on the table, this table has a query like this.

```
public function run()
{
    $books = [];
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $image_categories = ['abstract', 'animals', 'business', 'cats',
    'city', 'food',
    'nature', 'technics', 'transport'];
    for($i=0;$i<25;$i++){
      $title = $faker->sentence(mt_rand(3, 6));
      $title = str_replace('.', '', $title);
      $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($title));
      $category = $image_categories[mt_rand(0, 8)];
      $cover_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\larashop-api\public\images\books';
      $cover_fullpath = $faker->image( $cover_path, 300, 500,
      $category, true, true, $category);
      $cover = str_replace($cover_path . '/' , '', $cover_fullpath);
      $books[$i] = [
    'title' => $title,
    'slug' => $slug,
    'description' => $faker->text(255),
    'author' => $faker->name,
    'publisher' => $faker->company,
    'cover' => $cover,
    'price' => mt_rand(1, 10) * 50000,
    'weight' => 0.5,
    'status' => 'PUBLISH',
    'created_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    ];
    }
    DB::table('books')->insert($books);
        }
```

this Data like title, slug and all data is success input to the database , but this **cover** and I create a folder in **public/images/books** to save image . and its work, but this image name is not **valid**.

example in my folder my image name is: **qwertyuiop.jpg**

but in database the name is : **C:\xampp\htdocs\larashop-api\public\images\books\qwertyuiop.jpg**

I think its fault and will give an error . how I can solve this >

Comment: Just take cover path as :       $cover_path = 'images\books'; So your image path will be : images\books\qwertyuiop.jpg , and you can directly access it Url::to()

Answer (score 0):

You can get image name from `$cover_fullpath` by extract it :

```
$cover_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\larashop-api\public\images\books';
$cover_fullpath = $faker->image( $cover_path, 300, 500,$category, true, true, $category);
// after above code add this line so in cover_path you will have only image name
$cover_path = explode("\\",$cover_fullpath)[0];
```

Comment: i add image path with $cover_path = 'images\books'; ,, but having error :Cannot write to directory "images\books"

Comment: i want to save just image name . not with directory

Comment: Oke wait i will try this ,